# sqlite, counting foreign key references

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables, one that defines lists and another that defines items in the lists.  When i run this i only get lists that have items referencing them.  i really need to get a result for all rows in the lists table and a count of how many rows in the items table reference each list.

```
SELECT name, COUNT(items.listId) as itemCount
FROM lists 
INNER JOIN items 
ON lists._id = items.listId
GROUP BY items.listId
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing your `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, and change your `GROUP BY` to `lists._id`. I didn't test this!

Comment: thank you so much, i struggled with this for hours and you answered it in like 5 minutes.  huge help, thanks.